# mysql query showing empty in query

Tags: mysql, database, outer-join

how can i query like i want an output of this, something like i group it by my tbl_clinics.clinic_name. Now what happen to my query? why it is, it doesn't showing my zero values , like i want something output like these:

```
clinic name | total_check
 Clinic 1   |    4
 Clinic 2   |    0
 Clinic 3   |    0
 Clinic 4   |    0
```

Here is my query :

```
SELECT
tbl_clinics.clinic_name,
COALESCE(COUNT(tbl_check_up.check_up_id),0) AS total_check
FROM
tbl_clinics
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_check_up ON tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_check_up.clinic_id
WHERE tbl_clinics.user_id = "102" AND MONTH(tbl_check_up.check_up_date) = "02"  
GROUP BY tbl_clinics.clinic_name
```

and what i've got is only like these:

```
   clinic_name   |   total_check
    Clinic 1     |      4
```

why is that it doesn't showing my other clinics ? .. how can i manipulate these? . Please help me to have a correct output from what i've want and explain to me why is mine not doing well from the output that i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHERE clause will determine what rows will be outputted. If you wish to output all records within the table "tbl_clinics", try this:

```
SELECT tbl_clinics.clinic_name,
       Count(tbl_check_up.check_up_id) AS total_check
FROM   tbl_clinics
       LEFT JOIN tbl_check_up
              ON tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_check_up.clinic_id
                 AND tbl_clinics.user_id = "102"
                 AND Month(tbl_check_up.check_up_date) = "02"
GROUP  BY tbl_clinics.clinic_name
```

Also, I think that COALESCE() on COUNT() is unnecessary as COUNT() will always return 0, not NULL, when no row is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT tbl_clinics.clinic_name, 
       COALESCE(COUNT(tbl_check_up.check_up_id), 0) AS total_check 
FROM   tbl_clinics 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_check_up 
                    ON tbl_clinics.clinic_id = tbl_check_up.clinic_id 
WHERE  tbl_clinics.user_id = "102" 
       AND (tbl_check_up.check_up_date IS NULL 
              OR MONTH(tbl_check_up.check_up_date) = "02") 
GROUP  BY tbl_clinics.clinic_name
```